# calling php variable in Javascript chart

Tags: javascript, php, bar-chart

Hi I am trying to show value from database in a javascript chart. 
I tried ecoing the whole script, but it doesnt work.

Here is my code. Any clue on how to do that?

```
<body>
    <div style="width: 50%">
        <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
    </div>


<script>
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};

var barChartData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        }
    ]

}
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive : true
    });
}

</script>
</body>
```

I want to control these values:

```
labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],

data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
```

Comment: Server vs client side issue. Try checking out AJAX. That is if you are getting data from database. I'm not really seeing it in the code.

Comment: You can use your PHP variables in your script using <?php your_variable ?> Try This. It may work for you

Comment: Problem fixed. I called the php variable directly in the js.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to pass JSON string as parameter to JavaScript function which will have associative array like month: scaling factor as key value pair. then in the function you can parse JSON string and fetch required data and pass to chart function.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide an example.

Comment: Here is sample code :


$json = "[{'X':0,'Y':1.52},{'X':1,'Y':1.56},{'X':2,'Y':1.42},{'X':3,'Y':1.85},{'X':4,'Y':1.62}]";
$callscript =  "get_chart($json);";
 echo $callscript;
function get_chart(data)
{
 
   for(keyd in data)
 {
  alert(keyd);
 }
}